# How was Object class generated?

Tags: java, compilation

I am just curious to know how the classes (inside rt.jar provided by Oracle) like java.lang.Object, java.lang.String were generated from the .java source files. I think, it's not possible for their **javac** to compile them.

I tried to compile Dummy.java  containing "class Dummy{}"

lab@labb:~/Documents$ set PATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/bin

lab@labb:~/Documents$ set CLASSPATH=.

lab@labb:~/Documents$ javac -verbose Dummy.java

[parsing started RegularFileObject[Dummy.java]]

[parsing completed 12ms]

[search path for source files: .]

[search path for class files: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/classes,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar,.]

[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/**Object**.class)]]

[checking Dummy]

[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/**AutoCloseable**.class)]]

[wrote RegularFileObject[Dummy.class]]
[total 131ms]

Comment: Why do you think it's not possible for javac to compile them?

Comment: As each & every class directly/indirectly inherits from Object. Compiler needs to make syntactic & semantic checks of the inheritance hierarchy and referenced classes.

Comment: Perhaps you are missing the concept of a bootstrap JRE. System and javac classes are compiled with an already compiled Java library and tools. Similar the way to, say, C compilers written in C are generally compiled with the same C compiler.

Comment: So, there is a chicken-egg problem if we think of the 1st C compiler?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Yes. This link may help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)

Answer (score 2):

All classes can be expressed as Java code (as you can see here: http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/lang/package-index.html) and compiled by javac. `Object` is a special case insofar as when loaded by the VM, it will not get a superclass.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a decompiler ([JAD](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad/) by example) to see how would look source file for a .class.

In case of base classes there are some methods that need to be `native` and their implementation provided in system-dependent libraries like `dll` for Windows or `so` for Linux.

String has only one method native (intern). Object has more. There are classes in JRE that needs native to acomplish things related to SO and are very low-level, like atomic values or threads (thanks @yshavit), but the vast majority of the JRE library code is programmed in Java.

Comment: There are plenty of other native methods. For instance, `AtomicInteger.compareAndSet` uses `Unsafe.compareAndSwapInt`, which is native. `Thread` has several, and there are many more examples.